# Anyone know how tog get passed the following error?

Tags: ansible, yaml

So I have this error that I am getting, which is mind boggling.

[image: error message screenshot]

```
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'community.digitalocean.digital_ocean'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/playbook.yml': line 19, column 6, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


   - name: Create DigitalOcean SSH key
    ^ here
```

Here is my playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    digital_ocean_token:
    droplets:
      - ****
      - ****
      
  tasks:
    - name: Create SSH key
      user:
        name: "{{ansible_user_id}}"
        generate_ssh_key: yes
        ssh_key_type: rsa
        ssh_key_bits: 4096
        ssh_key_file: .ssh/id_rsa

    - name: Create DigitalOcean SSH key
      community.digitalocean.digital_ocean:
        state: present
        command: droplet
        name: "{{ item }}"
        unique_name: yes
        size_id: s-1vcpu-1gb
        region_id: nyc1
        image_id: centos-7-64x
        ssh_key_ids: "{{ my_ssh.ssh_key.id }}"
        api_taken: "{{ digital_ocean_token }}"
```

Comment: Paste the text of your error into the question. Images aren't searchable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the collection before running the playbook.

```sh
ansible-galaxy collection install community.digitalocean
```

[Reference](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/digitalocean/digital_ocean_module.html#community-digitalocean-digital-ocean-create-delete-a-droplet-ssh-key-in-digitalocean)

Comment: *facepalm* and you know what I thought of that but thought I already did that. Once that's done though do you have to do anything special for droplets?

Comment: Nope. You should be good to go once the collection is installed.